# Remove background from Image & take only Image part for save in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, uiimage, core-image, chromakey

This is what i need to achieve:

- Take image from camera or Gallery
- Remove background from image & save it
- Background should be anything black or white
- Also need to remove shadow along with the background

**Result Example:**

**Original Image**

[image]

**Result Image**

[image]

**This is what i have tried:**

```
CGFloat colorMasking[6]={222,255,222,255,222,255};
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors([IMG CGImage], colorMasking);
UIImage  *resultThumbImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:ThumbImage.scale orientation:IMG.imageOrientation];
```

Its only work on white background. Its not more effective. I need to achieve exact result what i have placed in above images.

I have also referred some references:

[iOS how to mask the image background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998097/ios-how-to-mask-the-image-background-color)

[How to remove the background of image in iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728021/how-to-remove-the-background-of-image-in-iphone-app)

[Changing the background color of a captured image from camera to white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220108/changing-the-background-color-of-a-captured-image-from-camera-to-white)

Can someone help me to achieve this ?

Any references or will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try to use Grabcut

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution.? please share here.. I have also facing same problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, as a rule of thumb, the more different the background color from all the other colors,
the easier it is to split the image into fore- and background. In such a case, as @Chris already
suggested, it is possible to use a simple chroma key implementation. Below is my quick
implementation of the keying described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key#Programming) (it's written in C++ but translating it to
Objective-C should be easy):

```
/**
 * @brief Separate foreground from background using simple chroma keying.
 *
 * @param imageBGR   Image with monochrome background
 * @param chromaBGR  Color of the background (using channel order BGR and range [0, 255])
 * @param tInner     Inner threshold, color distances below this value will be counted as foreground
 * @param tOuter     Outer threshold, color distances above this value will be counted as background
 *
 * @return  Mask (0 - background, 255 - foreground, [1, 255] - partially fore- and background)
 *
 * Details can be found on [Wikipedia][1].
 *
 * [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key#Programming
 */
cv::Mat1b chromaKey( const cv::Mat3b & imageBGR, cv::Scalar chromaBGR, double tInner, double tOuter )
{
    // Basic outline:
    //
    // 1. Convert the image to YCrCb.
    // 2. Measure Euclidean distances of color in YCrBr to chroma value.
    // 3. Categorize pixels:
    //   * color distances below inner threshold count as foreground; mask value = 0
    //   * color distances above outer threshold count as background; mask value = 255
    //   * color distances between inner and outer threshold a linearly interpolated; mask value = [0, 255]

    assert( tInner <= tOuter );

    // Convert to YCrCb.
    assert( ! imageBGR.empty() );
    cv::Size imageSize = imageBGR.size();
    cv::Mat3b imageYCrCb;
    cv::cvtColor( imageBGR, imageYCrCb, cv::COLOR_BGR2YCrCb );
    cv::Scalar chromaYCrCb = bgr2ycrcb( chromaBGR ); // Convert a single BGR value to YCrCb.

    // Build the mask.
    cv::Mat1b mask = cv::Mat1b::zeros( imageSize );
    const cv::Vec3d key( chromaYCrCb[ 0 ], chromaYCrCb[ 1 ], chromaYCrCb[ 2 ] );

    for ( int y = 0; y < imageSize.height; ++y )
    {
        for ( int x = 0; x < imageSize.width; ++x )
        {
            const cv::Vec3d color( imageYCrCb( y, x )[ 0 ], imageYCrCb( y, x )[ 1 ], imageYCrCb( y, x )[ 2 ] );
            double distance = cv::norm( key - color );

            if ( distance < tInner )
            {
                // Current pixel is fully part of the background.
                mask( y, x ) = 0;
            }
            else if ( distance > tOuter )
            {
                // Current pixel is fully part of the foreground.
                mask( y, x ) = 255;
            }
            else
            {
                // Current pixel is partially part both, fore- and background; interpolate linearly.
                // Compute the interpolation factor and clip its value to the range [0, 255].
                double d1 = distance - tInner;
                double d2 = tOuter   - tInner;
                uint8_t alpha = static_cast< uint8_t >( 255. * ( d1 / d2 ) );

                mask( y, x ) = alpha;
            }
        }
    }

    return mask;
}
```

A fully working code example can be found in this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/enpe/8634ce7f200fb554f0e5).

Unfortunately, your example does not stick to that rule of thumb. Since the foreground and
background only vary in intensity it is difficult (or even impossible) to find a single global set
of parameters for a good separation:

1. Black line around the object but no holes inside the object (`tInner=50`, `tOuter=90`)
   [image: mask 1]
   [image: background substitution 1]
2. No black line around the object but holes inside the object (`tInner=100`, `tOuter=170`)
   [image: mask 2]
   [image: background substitution 2]

So, if you cannot change the background of your images a more
complicated approach is required. However, a quick and simple example implementation is a bit out of scope, but you may want to look into related areas of [image segmentation](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=image+segmentation+support+vector+machines+bag+of+word) and 
[alpha matting](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=alpha+matting).

Comment: You are familiar with OpenCV and Objective-C, right? I ask, because your question suggests that you only need to find a suitable algorithm, not that you need detailed tutorial on porting it to a specific platform. If the latter is the case, then I'm out.

Comment: Of course I read it. Your bounty description doesn't with one word mention Objective-C as a requirement. It requests a *detailed canonical answer*. I also didn't fail to notice that you tagged your question with *opencv* which implies that (1) you wanted to target a larger audience (voila, here I am) and that (2) you are at least familiar with that library. Translating the OpenCV-related part of my answer from C++ to any other platform supported by OpenCV shouldn't be a big thing.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use a chromakey - although you are picking black I think it should work.

One quick google came up with [this](https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/blob/master/CIFunHouse/CIFunHouse/Custom%20Filters/ChromaKey.m)

Comment: Then chromakey is perfect